# Defining a function when the domain is a set of terms of a certain form.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $\phi(x),\psi(x)$ denote two terms and $A,B,C$ be sets. Assume $A=\{y\ |\ (\exists x\in B)(y=\phi(x))\}$. Suppose I want to define a map $g$ from $A$ to $C$. When can I use the rule $g:\phi(x)\mapsto\psi(x)$ to define $g:A\rightarrow C$?

The fact that every element of $A$ is of the form $\phi(x)$ for some $x\in B$ doesn't seem to be enough. For example, if there exist $x,x'\in B$ such that $\phi(x)=\phi(x')$ but $\psi(\phi(x))\ne\psi(\phi(x'))$. Then $g$ is not a function. In order to overcome this problem, is it enough to ensure that $A$ is the set
$\{y\ |\ (\exists! x\in B)(y=\phi(x))\}$?

Is there a general rule that regulates defining functions in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to check precisely is that if $x,x\in B$ are such that $\phi(x)=\phi(x')$, then $\psi(x)=\psi(x')$.  If you know this, then you can define $g(a)$ to be equal to $\psi(x)$ for any choice of $x\in B$ such that $a=\phi(x)$, and this value will be independent of the choice of $x$.  (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2110946/86856) for how you could define this more formally as a set of ordered pairs and prove that it has the desired properties.)  Checking this condition is commonly referred to as showing that $g:\phi(x)\mapsto\psi(x)$ is "well-defined".

In particular, if each element of $A$ is equal to $\phi(x)$ for a *unique* $x\in B$ (i.e., if the function $\phi$ is injective), then $g$ is automatically well-defined, since $\phi(x)=\phi(x')$ implies $x=x'$ and so $\psi(x)=\psi(x')$.